# SharePoint 2010 and Outlook 2013

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, outlook

I am using SharePoint 2010 and have meeting workspaces, how can I link and create new meeting workspaces from Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 2):

As per Technet this feature is not available, As this is deprecated  in outlook 2013.

> The Meeting workspaces feature is removed from Outlook. The entry
>   point commands to create Meeting Workspaces is removed from both the
>   Quick Access Toolbar and the Ribbon.
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954(v=office.15).aspx

You still able use the old created stuff(from 2010) but cannot create new as they mentioned.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-HA102892827.aspx#_Toc382936208